# Substituting a phrase with a name

Tags: phrases, sentence-structure

For example suppose in describing an application I say

> The user clicks on the "Try again" button and then...

Could I say sometimes

> The user clicks on the "Try again" and then ..

What this action is called, is there any rule to be considered in such cases?

Comment: The second phrase isn't a good way to say this, but you could say "The user clicks on "Try again" and then ..". *Try again* is still an adjective, not a noun, so no *the*.

Comment: @user3169 thank you, actually one of my concerns by saying *is there any rule* was that "the"

Comment: Well, you don't need  "the", but it 's because you dropped "button", which is what  "the" referred to!   And "Try again" is NOT an adjective in your latter example, for the same reason: with "button" gone, there is no noun to modify; so "try again" does become the noun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common possibilities here:

(1) You can spell out that it's a button by mentioning it outright, as in your example: click on the "Try Again" button; or

(2) If it's obvious that you're talking about a button, you can just say: click on "Try Again." Also, the verb click makes it obvious that it's something clickable.

Comment: Note that if you use "try again"  without "button", you must render the spelling, capitalization, (and punctuation if any) exactly as they appear on the button, (and even imitate the font; then you can leave off the quote marks.) Better yet, if you can: capture/crop an image of the actual button.  Then you won't need to say "button" even on first mention. BTW,  you **never** have to say  "on" when describing clicking a button. "Click" takes a direct object.  **Click X**, not **Click on X**.  (Trust me. I'm a technical writer for an IT department.)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thank you for the point, you mean I don't need "The" if it's a clickable object (like button, link), otherwise it needs?

Comment: No, I meant you say  "Click the [foo] button" but not "Click the [foo]".  It's just "Click [foo]."  I didn't say anything about non-clickable objects.  But if there is _text_ that is clickable, e.g. a _link_, I might say "Click on "blah blah blah".